# TIniFile.WriteBinaryStream creates exception

Tags: delphi, stream, ini, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, I try to save a valid `TPicture` base64-encoded to an INI file:

```
procedure TForm1.SavePictureToIniFile(const APicture: TPicture);
var
  LInput: TMemoryStream;
  LOutput: TMemoryStream;
  MyIni: TIniFile;
  ThisFile: string;
begin
  if FileSaveDialog1.Execute then
    ThisFile := FileSaveDialog1.FileName
  else EXIT;

  LInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LOutput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    APicture.SaveToStream(LInput);
    LInput.Position := 0;
    TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(LInput, LOutput);
    LOutput.Position := 0;

    MyIni := TIniFile.Create(ThisFile);
    try
      MyIni.WriteBinaryStream('Custom', 'IMG', LOutput); // Exception# 234
    finally
      MyIni.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LInput.Free;
    LOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`WriteBinaryStream` creates an exception:

> ERROR_MORE_DATA 234 (0xEA) More data is available.

Why? What does this mean? How can this problem be solved?

**EDIT:** Taking into consideration what @Uwe Raabe and @Andreas Rejbrand said, this code (which does not use base64-encoding) now works:

```
procedure TForm1.SavePictureToIniFile(const APicture: TPicture);
var
  LInput: TMemoryStream;
  MyIni: System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile;
  ThisFile: string;
begin
  if FileSaveDialog1.Execute then
    ThisFile := FileSaveDialog1.FileName
  else EXIT;

  LInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    APicture.SaveToStream(LInput);
    LInput.Position := 0;

    MyIni := TMemIniFile.Create(ThisFile);
    try
      MyIni.WriteBinaryStream('Custom', 'IMG', LInput);
      MyIni.UpdateFile;
    finally
      MyIni.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LInput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should either use WriteBinaryStream without Base64 encoding or encode to Base64 and use WriteString instead. Base64 is already a textual representation. Taking that as binary stream doubles the memory needed.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Not to mention that the result string *isn't even the Base64-encoded version of the image*!

Comment: (Just note that the current solution doesn't actually use Base64.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a limitation in the operating system's functions for handling INI files; the string is too long for it.

If you instead use the Delphi INI file implementation, [`TMemIniFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile), it works just fine. Just don't forget to call `MyIni.UpdateFile` at the end.

Yes, this is indeed a limitation in [the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa), as demonstrated by the following minimal example:

```
var
  wini: TIniFile;
  dini: TMemIniFile;
begin

  wini := TIniFile.Create('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\winini.ini');
  try
    wini.WriteString('General', 'Text', StringOfChar('W', 10*1024*1024));
  finally
    wini.Free;
  end;

  dini := TMemIniFile.Create('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\pasini.ini');
  try
    dini.WriteString('General', 'Text', StringOfChar('D', 10*1024*1024));
    dini.UpdateFile;
  finally
    dini.Free;
  end;
```

(Recall that INI files were initially used to store small amounts of configuration data in the 16-bit Windows era.)

**Also**, [Uwe Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe) is right: you should save the Base64 string as text.

Comment: BTW: Isn't there a kind of BinaryStream that automatically COMPRESSES its data? That would be very useful!

Comment: @user1580348: Maybe you can use the `TZipFile` for that?

Comment: Should I use `TZCompressionStream` from `System.ZLib` or from `ZLibEx`? Which is better?

Comment: @user1580348: No idea!

Comment: I have created a new question, as compressing the stream with ZLib seems to not work with my implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217195/writebinarystream-compressed-to-ini-file

Comment: I have now tried to REVERSE the whole process, i.e. load the data from the INI file back to a `TPicture`, but run into problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226950/load-base64-encoded-data-from-ini-file-back-to-tpicture