# WriteBinaryStream compressed to INI file?

Tags: delphi, stream, zlib, ini, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, I try to save a valid TPicture **compressed** to an INI file, trying to replicate the [ZLibCompressDecompress example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/ZLibCompressDecompress_(Delphi)) from the documentation:

```
procedure TForm1.SavePictureToIniFile(const APicture: TPicture);
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216011/tinifile-writebinarystream-creates-exception
var
  LInput: TMemoryStream;
  LOutput: TMemoryStream;
  MyIni: System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile;
  ThisFile: string;
  LZip: TZCompressionStream;
begin
  if FileSaveDialog1.Execute then
    ThisFile := FileSaveDialog1.FileName
  else EXIT;

  LInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LOutput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LZip := TZCompressionStream.Create(clDefault, LOutput);
  try
    APicture.SaveToStream(LInput);
    LInput.Position := 0;
    //LOutput.Position := 0;
    LZip.CopyFrom(LInput, LInput.Size);

    MyIni := TMemIniFile.Create(ThisFile);
    try
      MyIni.WriteBinaryStream('Custom', 'IMG', LOutput);
      MyIni.UpdateFile;
    finally
      MyIni.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LInput.Free;
    LOutput.Free;
    LZip.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But the stream is not saved in the INI file. The resulting INI file contains only these lines:

> [Custom]
> IMG=

So how can I save the compressed stream in the INI file?

Comment: Just a minor hint: always destroy objects in the reverse order of creation, especially when they might depend on each other. (This is one of the benefits of always using one `try..finally` per resource: then you cannot get the order wrong!)

Comment: You don't want to be using zlib surely. Images are already compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `LOutput.Position := 0` *after* the `LZip.CopyFrom` line, that is, immediately *before*

```
MyIni.WriteBinaryStream('Custom', 'IMG', LOutput);
```

Comment: Thank you, the compression reduced the size of the INI file from 840 KB to 640 KB (the TPicture coming from a 300 KB image).

Comment: It will be even smaller if you encode the compressed binary data using Base64 instead of raw hex.

Comment: You are right: Using your example from your answer to my previous question (without LZip compression), the size of the INI file was reduced to 567 KB. But how to optimize the result even further with LZIP compression? Is it possible to LZip-compress the Base64 string?

Comment: @user1580348: If you compress the Base64 string, you get a new blob of binary data, which you again need to encode using Base64 to get it to fit inside an INI file. I don't think there is much to gain by doing so, certainly not worth the additional complexity. If you want to compress even more, you need to give up the idea of string binary data in a text file. Maybe you could use a ZIP file that includes (1) INI files for all textual data and (2) separate image files instead of using an INI file with binary blobs inside it?

Comment: You are right: I've tried the ZLib string compression which indeed creates binary characters which I think are not secure to store in an INI file. However, I use the INI file format for something other which I cannot reveal right now. So for that your example with `TBase64Encoding` is the best compromise so far.

Comment: If size is an issue, there are other binary-to-text encodings that are smaller than base64, such as yEnc